# How to compile to form a DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, project, exe

I have sample project codes. When I compile it inside Visual C++, it produce as EXE. I would like to know, how can I change the final output to DLL form. Means that, when I compile, it become DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nut shell, a **dynamic link library (DLL)** is a collection of small programs, which can be called upon when needed by the **executable program (EXE)** that is running.

E.g Suppose, it would be if the **program (exe)** needs to get the free space of your hard drive. It can call the **DLL** file that contains the function with parameters and a call function. The **DLL** will then tell the executable the free space. This allows the **executable program** to be smaller in size and not have to write the function that has already exists

You can check  the required steps here : [How to Create a Simple Win32 DLL](http://www.icynorth.com/development/createdlltutorial.html) ?

Answer (score 2):

Compiling it as a DLL is comparatively easy, namely you set the "Configuration Type" in Configuration -> General in the project properties to "Dynamic Link Library".

However this isn't going to accomplish much unless you also export the entry point(s) into the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project choose "Class Library" in the New Project dialog:

[image]